# windows programming using template in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I am interested in writing simple windows-based programs for scientific calculations in c++. Is there a place I could find source code for a template that I could use? The window I would create would hardly ever vary -- it would be something similar to this (but simpler!):

http://www.lisisoft.com/imglisi/6/Science/73401version4xp.jpg

I am not a c++ programmer -- but I have created similar programs in visual basic (blush!). This is my way of learning c++ by working within a limited range of program design...mainly at first just changing the formulas and a few labels.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: All the windowing systems available are either C or an old bastardization of C++.  Learning these isn't a good way to learn C++.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a better place to ask specific questions, if you have any...

Comment: I wouldn't suggest learning c++ by programming a windows GUI (although I really like c++ in general), no matter how trivial the GUI app is. IMO VB or C# is the right way to do windows (GUI) programs.

Comment: thanks kevin for your input...

Comment: I suggest a change to your vocabulary: *stencil* instead of `template`.  The `template` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: @Thomas - would he have to change his vocabulary again, if he decides to dabble in 3D programming? :)

Comment: @Thomas: the term you're looking for is "boilerplate code".

Comment: @Cory Nelson: Uhm... Qt?

Comment: Qt, Gtk++, WxWidgets etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks to all who gave input to a newcomer!  -Allen

Answer (score 1):

First off, there are a million things you need to know before you can just download some code from somewhere and try to work with it. My best advice would be to pick up an "Introduction to C++" book.

But, putting that aside, I will try to answer the question.
There are 2 main ways to make GUI apps in windows using C++:

1. Get a C++ GUI library, there is an extensive list [here](http://wtl.wikispaces.com/OtherGuiLibraries).
2. Work with the [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) directly.

Once you have choosen either step 1 or 2, try to search for samples by searching the library name you have chosen followed by the word "samples" or "examples" (i.e, "WxWidgets Samples", "Qt examples" or "Windows API examples")

However, either way you choose, in order to make something like the example in your picture, I would estimate that it would take you at least 6 months (and thats if you program everyday).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I am new at this -- guess I have a long way to go!  -Allen

Answer (score 0):

For a windows C++ GUI library try reliable software library at www.relisoft.com. If you want to use native windows GUI programming you can also try using QT libraries.

Comment: Thanks Ghita. I looked at the site -- will study it and see if it can help me.